# Adding Pull Request support to the repository

Tags: git

We have a git repo hosted on our own server (not BitBucket, GitHub, etc). I would like to add a **Pull Request** functionality to it. Best would be to have a very simple web dashboard as well.

Is it doable using some open source tools? We can't host our repo on 3rd party servers due to our security policy.

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) may be just what you want. They call them [merge requests](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests), but it has them.

It also has [many other GitHub-like features](https://about.gitlab.com/features/)

Comment: Can you add more information? Answers that don't detail how the software matches each requirement in the question are subject to deletion.

Comment: @Undo added more info